# Vue component/data not rendering

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a python project (using flask) where I am trying to use Vue with. The problem is that nothing vue related renders if I go peek the html definition.
I've installed vue via npm, also installed webpack and laravel-mix. They seem to be well configured.

I have the instance

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import alert from './components/Alert.vue';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  data: {
    test: 'is it working?'
  },
  components: {
    alert
  }
});
```

The component

```html
<template>
  <div class="alert" v-text="message"></div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'alert',
    data() {
      return {
        message: 'I am an alert.'
      };
    }
  };

</script>

<style>
  .alert {
    background: red;
  }

</style>
```

And I am just trying to render the message

```html
<div class="mdl-card__title mdl-color--primary mdl-color-text--white relative">
  <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Login</h2>
</div>

<div id="app">
  [[ test ]]
</div>
```

but when I try peeking in the html I see nothing.
[Component not showing bellow the Login h2 tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXAYS.png)

Package.json

```json
{
  "name": "I've hidden it",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "<h1>I've hidden it</h1>",
  "main": "webpack.mix.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "i've hidden it"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "laravel-mix": "6.0.6",
    "postcss": "8.1",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.14"
  }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Have you installed Vue devtools? Does it detect vue? How do you serve the Vue app? Can you show your package.json file? Are there any warnings/errors being thrown when you run the start/serve/run command for your vue app?

Comment: No no errors at all. I've installed vue webtools but it is not detecting any vue js. Also, I tried with the vue script and even with it, devtools doesn't seem to find vue in the application. I'll put the package.json here

Also, no error pops up when I run it.

Comment: So when you run `npm run development` in your terminal, it shows you Vue app is running on localhost:8080 as usual? but when you browse localhost:8080, vue devtools doesn't detect vue?

Comment: Exactly. Laravel mix builds successfully, no errors popping up in the console. Nothing, just runs on localhost:8080.

Comment: Did you add `mix.js('src/app.js', 'public/js').vue();` in webpack.mix.js? Did you import the compiled script `./js/app.js` into your html? Does the js file show up in browser's sources tab?

Comment: Pardon the questions, all the Vue code you've provided looks good. The problem is probably in your configuration, about which you haven't added much.

Comment: Yes, just like this `mix.js('web/app/static/js/main.js', 'public/js').vue();`. But what do you mean by import the compiled script?

Comment: Okay seems I have narrowed down the problem, will add it as an answer, we can continue in the answer's comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On running `npm mix`, laravel-mix will compile the file you've provided to `mix.js` function and save it to the second parameter of the function, which is `public/js` directory in your project. The `.vue()` tells laravel-mix that it is a vue app entry point.

Once its compiled, you need to import the compiled scripts into your html.

```
<script src="public/js/main.js"/>
```

Now your Vue app should work fine.

Comment: Well I did that and it doesn't work. The following message pops up in the console : `GET http://localhost:8080/public/js/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)`

Comment: Please give output of `npm mix` and tell us your directory structure.

Comment: Now it works! my application wasn't able for some reason to find the main file in the js public folder, but adding the compiled script to the html worked.

Comment: Now I know why. Once it was a wep app inside of a python project, the public folder wasn't being seen because it was above the domain of the web app

Comment: I suspected that, that's why I asked for the directory structure. Glad to hear it's working.